# Как изменить место вывода данных из python?

Tags: python, консоль, environment-variables

При выполнение такого кода на python `print("Hello, world")` результат отобразиться в консоле PyCharme/Xcode/VSCode и тд. Как изменить место вывода этого результата? То есть, чтобы python печатал ***по умолчанию*** в другое место (файл на рабочем столе, например).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хорошей практикой считается [пайплайн](https://dzen.ru/a/XjbGV1LTKHqMggr1) в какой-то файл, название которого может быть любым — файл создастся, если он отсутствует:

```bash
python some_file.py > file_on_desktop.txt
```

Но судя по тому, что вы запускаете код из IDE, другим подходящим in-code решением может стать следующий контекстный менеджер, внутри которого нужно выполнять код, чтобы вывод был перенаправлен в файл.

```py
import sys


with open('file_on_desktop.txt', 'w') as sys.stdout:
    print('Hello, world')
```

В обоих случая в файле **file_on_desktop.txt** появится строка «Hello, world».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Он помог, но это не то, что я ожидал. Желательно решение, которое не требует доп. кода на python (максимум изменение через python какой-то окружающей переменной). Я разрабатываю IDE и мне надо создать вывод данных на консоль.

Answer (score 1):

В коде из ответа выше будет сложно вернуть вывод в stdout.

Можно использовать `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, так:

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        # какой-то код
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).

Comment: Спасибо. Если можно было поставить две галочки, то я бы поставил и на ваш ответ тоже.